# Python regex match escaped char

Tags: python, regex

I need to match groups like:

```
:data:
:abc'e12\:3\:text:
```

in a string, meaning

```
:(?P<data>.*?):
```

but to also allow escaped colon `\:`

My best try looks like this:

```
:(?P<data>((?<=\\):|.)*?):
```

Comment: Did you try using the start and end anchors to match the first and last colons? (i.e. using `^` and `$`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p = re.compile(r':((\\:|[^:])+):')
print p.match(":abc'e12\:3\:text:").group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make sure you are getting the start and end characters with "^" and "$":

```
^:(.+):$
```

You can substitute ".+" with the type of regex you want too.

Comment: To be more precise, this would only match the whole string. Thanks for your time, anyway